# Web Server Caches - in-memory vs the OS

Tags: apache, web-services, caching, operating-system, varnish

I'm not entirely sure if this question would be better suited for something like Serverfault - however, since I'm a programmer, and not a sys-admin, I'm asking from the perspective of a programmer.

These days there are a HUGE number of options available for caching static web content.  Things like Varnish or Squid are used throughout the industry.

However, I'm somewhat confused here.  From a theoretical perspective, I don't see how the caching of *static* content requires the use of some 3rd party software apart from the web-server and OS.

Dynamic-content, (such as, the result of an expensive PHP script calculation or something), certainly could benefit from a good caching system.

But with static content, what do we gain by caching resources in memory?  Wouldn't the OS page cache *already* provide the same benefits as a dedicated caching system like Varnish or Squid?  Or am I missing some of the benefits?

Varnish, in fact, stores data in Virtual Memory using `mmap` - and lets the OS handle the page swapping.  So, how exactly is this even different from just saving cached resources to disk and opening them with `fread`?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. For static resources, the memory can just as well be put to use for the page cache instead of using Varnish.

Chaining caches (varnish, pagecache) for identical content that compete for the same resource (server memory) is silly.

If you in addition have some dynamic content, you may choose to combine and serve everything from cache due to operational reasons. For example is it simpler to collect access logs and statistics from a single software stack, than two. This also applies to things like staff training and security patching.